# Flexbox - Scrollbar moves centered content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, scrollbar

Flexbox with two columns. Each one has a centered content with a *max-width* of X. The second column has *overflow-y* set to *scroll*.
Obviously the scrollbar needs space and moves the centered content of the second column to the left.
Is there a way to have the contents still exactly below the other?

HTML:

```
<header>
    <nav>nav</nav>
</header>
<main>
    <section>section</section>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100vh;
}
body {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
header {
flex: 0 0 auto;
}
main {
flex: 1 1 auto;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
nav {
width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
section {
width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

See: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpXvyN

Comment: You can't reliably compensate for the width of the scrollbar because that varies across browsers. For example, Safari vertical scroll is thinner than in Chrome. Not sure how to get around this in your case, unless you want to add a vertical scroll to the element above or accept a slight misalignment as you have now.

Answer (score 1):

A hacky fix would be to add the following line to the 'section' element CSS:

```
transform: translate(8px, 0);
```

It will move the 'section' element 8px to the right to account for the scrollbar.
Tested working in Chrome and IE on Win 7 :/

Comment: This could be a nice approach +1... but take in care the comment of Michael_B on the question